# Ecto after_create callback or similar

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Is there any callback in Ecto that runs after database is created, i.e. after `ecto.create`?

I am using Cassandra with Ecto using [ecto-cassandra](https://github.com/cafebazaar/ecto-cassandra), and I need to change some keyspace options. The best place is to it after create.

Although, it is possible to do it in a migration, preferably in the first one, but having an `after_create` callback makes the intention more clear.

Comment: What is the problem with having it done in a migration? There is no callback that does this.

Comment: The problem is the intention. Say I want to do something exactly after creation of database, which is essential to the whole database. Migrations can be used, but it makes things a bit less obvious. Since we already have `after_connect` callback, I though maybe this should be there too. Maybe even `after_drop`.

Comment: I think `after_connect` is there because it is runtime thing - maybe you want to make log record, or something everytime it is connected. Creating database is one-off thing, therefore I think that is the reason why it is not available as a callback from within the application itself. I would say doing something in the first migration, if you name it something like `SetupDatabase` and add some comments, will be pretty clear.

Comment: It seems it is. But what about `ecto.drop` too? `after_drop` callback maybe? It may seem it is a special case, but anyway it can't be done through migrations.

Comment: Consider using custom mix tasks for that - namely wrappers for `create` and `drop` with your logic within.

Comment: @PatNowak That can be used too. However, I have a feeling that it's a bit *hackish*. Seems like I have no other option for now.